# How to have a sequence variable within a for loop

Tags: python

```
        def main():

            for row in range (7):
                assignment = int(1)
                if row == 1:
                    for assignment_number in range(0,8):
                        assignment_number+1

                for i in range(0,7):
                    assignment_mark = float(input(("Please enter your mark for assginment" assignment_number,": "))

                    assignment_weight = float(input("Please enter the total weight percentage for the assignment: "))

            main()
```

So this is my code above,

I'm basically trying to work out how I could say for each input variable "Please enter your mark for assignment x (from 1 up to 7).

Which will loop, so once they enter it for assignment 1, it then asks the same question for assignment 2.

I hope this makes some sense. I'm new to programming in general and this just happens to also be my first post on stack! Be gentle (: 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let the loop do the counting, then use string formatting.

And you only need a single loop to collect each pair of events

```
from collections import namedtuple 

Assignment = namedtuple("Assignment", "mark weight") 

assignments = [] 
for idx in range(7):
    print("Please enter data for assignment {}".format(idx+1)) 
    mark = float(input("mark: "))
    weight = float(input("weight:"))
    assignments.append(Assignment(mark, weight)) 
print(assignments)
```

Comment: Nice idea, using `namedtuple`, but I'd suggest adding the assignment number to the tuple, otherwise it will be tricky to find the right one, more so since assignments start with 1, not 0.

Comment: How would it be tricky if the list is stored in insert order?

Comment: It might be a tiny bit confusing if `assignments[4]` is actually the assignment number 5; adding the index to the tuple would make that a bit clearer.

Comment: Off by one errors are just one of those two things that are hard in computer science ;)

Comment: BTW, could you fix the syntax error? It gives your code a bad smell of not being tested (although it works after fixing the error)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code:

- `assignment_number+1` without assigning it to a variable does nothing, and even if you did, that value would be lost after the loop. If you want to offset the numbers by one, you can just use `range(1, 8)` or do `+1` when you actually need that value of that variable
- in your second loop, your loop variable is `i`, but you are using `assignment_number` from the previous loop, which still has the value from the last execution, 7
- you have to store the values for `assignments_mark` and `assignment_weight` somewhere, e.g. in two lists, a list of tuples, or a dict of tuples; since assignment numbers start with 1 and not 0, I'd recommend a `dict`

You can try something like this, storing the marks and weights for the assignments in a dictionary:

```
assignments = {}
for i in range(7):
    assignment_mark = float(input("Please enter your mark for assginment %d: " % (i+1)))
    assignment_weight = float(input("Please enter the total weight percentage for the assignment: "))
    assignments[i+1] = (assignment_mark, assignment_weight)

print(assignments)
```

Comment: That's actually a set of tuples

Comment: @cricket_007 Nope.

Comment: `{}` makes an empty set or empty dict. No? There is no key for your values, so I think `type(assignments) == set `

Comment: @cricket_007 Last time I checked (about 10 seconds ago), `{}` creates an empty dict; only `{1,2,3,...}` makes a `set`, and I'm using keys `[i+1]`, so it's a dict.